# Como poner en mi tabla en JSON jQuery un pdf de sql?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, sql-server

Quisiera que se pudiera abrir mi archivo pdf que almacené en mi tabla sql con los siguientes campos: `nombre(varchar),tipo(varchar),ruta(varbinary)`. Cómo sería?

Así lo tengo pero solo me trae el nombre como abro el pdf???

```
function OnSuccess(response) {

    var Data = jQuery.parseJSON(response.d);

    $("#tbDatos").html("");
    $('#tbDatos').append('<table id="example"><thead><tr><th style="display: none">Id </th><th>Nombre</th><th>nomArchivo</th></table>');
    var table = $('#tbDatos').children().addClass("display");
    for (var i = 0; i < Data.length; i++) {
   table.append("<tr id='row_" + i + "'><td style='display: none'>" + Data[i].id + "</td><td name='nombre'>" + Data[i].nombre "</td>" + "<td name='nomArchivo'>" + "<a href='AquiVaTuDominio.com/'"; + Data[i].ruta + "target='_blank'>" + Data[i].nomArchivo + "</a></td></td></tr>")
```

Ya tengo el archivo almacenado, sólo quiero leerlo

- poner una columna del archivo pdf un link por ejemplo y
- al darle un click sobre el nombre de archivo este se abra el pdf.

Estoy utilizando: `ASP.net WebForms` `C#` `SQL Server`

Comment: Oye pero haber, quiero entenderte, lo que tu buscas es **leer** un archivo .PDF, almacenar los datos que contiene este archivo .PDF y después ¿guardarlos en tu Base de Datos?

Comment: Hola Araceli, bienvenida a SOes, para mejorar en la redacción de preguntas, te recomiendo esta lectura:  http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Recuerda que entre mejor definida y detallada esté la pregunta, mejor calidad de respuestas tendrás. Saludos :)

Comment: ya tengo el archivo almacenado,quiero leerlo 1)poner una columna del archivo pdf un link por ejemplo y 2)osea darle un click sobre el nombre de archivo y este se abra el pdf

Comment: Ok ya te entendí un poco mejor, ahora te recomiendo que nos indiques que datos son los que tienes ya desde tu Base de datos, esto para poder armar el script y comentarte como puedes hacerlo.

Comment: asi lo tengo table.append("<tr id='row_" + i + "'><td style='display: none'>" + Data[i].id + "</td><td name='nombre'>" + Data[i].nombre "</td>" + "<td name='nomArchivo'>" + "<a href='http://AquiVaTuDominio.com/'" + Data[i].ruta + "target='_blank'>" + Data[i].nomArchivo + "</a></td></td></tr>"); ahora como abro el archivo pdf al dar click sobre el link..perodon es que apenas aprendo este lenguaje

Comment: alguien tiene una idea de como abrir pdf? gracias.

Comment: código en camino :D

Comment: hola: me marca  error:
Server Error in '/' Application.
Invalid attempt to read when no data 
Description:
Source Error:
Line 35:{ 
Line 36: sdr.Read();
Line 37:ruta = (byte[])sdr["ruta"];
si funciona el  Generic Handler (*.ashx) FileCS 
porque si en el select le pongo un id=1009 si me muestra el pdf, 
pero lo vuelvo a poner id=@id y me marca ese error, asi lo tengo en m tabla tal vez aqui esta el error y yo no veo:
"<td name='nomArchivo'>" + "<a href='http://localhost:25129/FileCS.ashx?='" + Data[i].id+ "target='_blank'>" + Data[i].nomArchivo + "</a></td></td></tr>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si tienes la ruta en la BD y la tienes en `Data`, deberías mostrar un link con un target blank que apunte a la ruta del archivo dando como resultado una descarga de archivo al dar click en el enlace, mira:

```
table.append("<tr id='row_" + i + "'><td style='display: none'>" + Data[i].id + "</td><td name='nombre'>" + Data[i].nombre "</td>" + "<td name='nomArchivo'>" + "<a href='http://AquiVaTuDominio.com/'" + Data[i].ruta + " target='_blank'>" + Data[i].nomArchivo + "</a></td></td></tr>");
```

**Actualización**

Ahora conociendo a detalle las características de cómo se esta construyendo el software, aquí una mejor respuesta:

Primero creamos un Generic Handler (*.ashx) llamado `FileCS` en la raíz del proyecto con el siguiente código:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="FileCS" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
public class FileCS : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        //Aqui falta algo importante: saber si el usuario está autenticado para darle la seguridad del caso
        int id = int.Parse(context.Request.QueryString["IdDeMiPDF"]);
        byte[] bytesDelPDF;
        string fileName, contentType;
        //De aqui sacamos la cadena de conexion
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT nombre, ruta, tipo FROM nombreDeLaTabla WHERE Id=@IdDeMiPDF";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdDeMiPDF", id);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    sdr.Read();
                    bytesDelPDF = (byte[])sdr["ruta"];
                    contentType = sdr["tipo"].ToString();
                    fileName = sdr["nombre"].ToString();
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        context.Response.Buffer = true;
        context.Response.Charset = "";       
        context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);        
        context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytesDelPDF);
        context.Response.Flush();
        context.Response.End();
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Segundo, definir la llamada a dicho archivo enviando el ID

```
ResolveUrl("~/FileCS.ashx?IdDeMiPDF=") //Y le agregas el ID, esto corre en el lado del servidor, tienes que ver cual es la ruta del archivo y lo llamas.
```

En tu `javascript` la idea va así:

Cambiar esto

```
"<a href='http://AquiVaTuDominio.com/'" + Data[i].ruta + "target='_blank'>"
```

Por algo similar:

```
"<a href='http://AquiVaTuDominio.com/FileCS.ashx?IdDeMiPDF='" + Data[i].id+ "target='_blank'>"
```

Ten en cuenta dónde está el archivo `FileCS.ashx`.

Referencia: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Retrieve-and-display-PDF-Files-from-database-in-browser-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41536/discussion-on-answer-by-fredyfx-como-poner-en-mi-tabla-en-json-jquery-un-pdf-de). @fredyfx, no es la primera vez, por favor evita este tipo de actividades.